# Group by Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following query:

```
$orders = Order::where(function ($query) use ($request) {

            // Filter by in process delivery
            if ($request->get("status") && $request->get("status") == "2") {
                $query->where('status', "2");
            }

        })->groupBy('created_at')->get();
```

When I try to execute this query I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'delivery.order.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `order` group by `created_at`)
```

What is problem?

Comment: The problem is you are trying to select a column (or even columns) that is not in group clause. What exactly you are trying to achieve? Why are you grouping it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `config/database.php` file, change `mysql` configuration array

from `'strict' => true`

to `'strict' => false`

For more information about this error read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the final query `` select * from `order` group by `created_at` ``. It's trying to select every column, but its grouping only one. Your database is working in [only full group mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) which means all selected fields have to be in group by clause (or have to be aggregator functions like `SUM`, `COUNT` etc.)

I don't know what you really want to get from this query but you can select columns manually like this:

```
$orders = Order::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    if ($request->get("status") && $request->get("status") == "2") {
        $query->where('status', "2");
    }
})->groupBy('created_at')
  //select columns like this
  ->select(\DB::raw('COUNT(*)'), 'created_at')
  ->get();
```

Another option is to disable `full group` mode but the result will be unexpected and probably that's not what you want.